# Instant Apps option is missing in android studio

Tags: android-instant-apps, android-studio-4.0

Any idea you guys why I don't see this option "This project will support instant apps" option? I'm suspecting its because of the recent update. Absolute beginner here, so I'm clueless since google didn't yield any results regarding this. Also the option "use androidx.* artifacts" used to be here, which also seems to have vanished. [image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a project first because you need to have an app to have a InstantApp, inside your project you can add a dynamic-feature module that will be your instantApp.

You need to include this dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0"
```

After sync gradle you can go to File > New > New Module > here you will see the option for dynamic features and Instant Dynamic Feature Module

[image: Android Studio new module menu]

Important: when looking on web for Instant implementation pay attention because the first way released by google to implement is now deprecated, so in 2019(maybe end of 2018) it changes. Sometimes you might find an old post telling to do declare the module differently.

Extra reading:

Setup InstantApp: [click here](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#top_of_page)

Android Bundle docs: [click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Android Studio, that `AndroidX` is now the new default.

You can verify it in the `gradle.properties` files with values as

```java
android.useAndroidX=true
```